# What does `cin >> variable` in while mean?

Tags: c++

I'm currently learning C++, and I've encountered the following code:

```
int n, g;

while(cin >> n >> g) // <--------------
    // ... snip ...
```

What does the marked line mean? Does it mean "While n is greater or equal to g"? And cin >=n?

Comment: `cin` is a standard input variable.  The `>>` operator is an overloaded operator on the input stream object type that allows capturing input from the keyboard.

Comment: Please read a book and start with `#include <iostream> int main() { std::cout << "Hello World\n"; }`

Comment: I googled "C++ tutorials", picked a random result, and the first tutorial in the series explained what `>>` does with `cin`.

Comment: @JosephMansfield please don't be a troll

Comment: @jerry I don't think Joseph is trying to be a "troll". He is saying that you could have Googled for "c++ cin" or "c++ tutorial" and found the answer to your question relatively easily.

Comment: he was a troll , and I don't think any beginner would like to join SO if they are received by  people like him , i'm sorry

Comment: @jerry I think you are reading my comment in a way that is different to how I wrote it. I'm trying to tell you that you need to try figuring these things out before you ask about them, and in this case that just means reading a basic C++ tutorial. If you hover over the downvote button, you'll see that it says "does not show any research effort". This is how Stack Overflow works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

">>"  is the input stream operator.  That code is trying to read two integers from the stardard input stream.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/

Comment: thanks , but what does the while part do ? It executes until what?

Comment: @jerry I think it will probably read until and EOF is received.

Answer (score 4):

`while (expr) body` will execute the `body` as long as the expression `expr` is true(-ish). So what does `cin >> n >> g` actually do?

[`cin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream) is the standard input stream. Usually the stuff someone types in with a keyboard. We can extract values of this stream, using the [`>>` operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt). So `cin >> n;` reads an integer. However, the result of `(cin >> variable)` is a reference to `cin`. Therefore
 we can again use `>>` in order to get more values from the stream: `cin >> n >> g`.

This is equivalent to `cin >> n; cin >> g;`. So we now know that `cin >> n >> g` takes two integer values from the input stream and returns a reference to `cin`. However, if you recall correctly, I said that the expression in the while statement needs to be true. How can an input stream be true?

Well, there's an [operator for that too](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool). It calls another function, called [`good`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/good), which returns `true` if the stream is in a good state, and `false` if it isn't. The stream is in a good state as long as we can operate on it. When we've reached the *end of the stream*, we can no longer take values from it (we're at the end, right?) and therefore the state isn't good anymore.

At that point the expression in while evaluates to false.

**TL;DR**: It takes two integer values until there aren't enough values left or the operation has failed.